# Using kendo ui in Asp.net boilerplate project

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, kendo-asp.net-core

I have a question, i am recently investigating asp.net boilerplate as I would like to implement it in the application I am currently developing, my application is mvc5 and I am using kendo widgets throughout the application, I manage  to migrate to asp.net core boilerplate template and successfully included all the libraries and references, however i came to realize that ABP formats json responses that kendo widgets no longer accepts. Thinking about this makes it complicated and maybe the combination is not that easy.

Did anyone ever encounter similar situation and if so how did you go about it, thx.

Comment: the official abp git repo has a sample related to KendoUi and Abp, have you looked into it? https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate-samples/tree/master/KendoUiDemo

Comment: yes i did, found it not very useful , it is more setting kendo Ref files in a solution. but does not show an example of a any widget, this is were i am facing difficulties,